# Laravel Sanctum Session Not Shared Across Subdomains in Nuxt App

Tags: nuxt.js, session-cookies, laravel-sanctum

I'm facing an issue with sharing Laravel Sanctum sessions across subdomains in a Nuxt.js app. Here's the breakdown of my setup:

Laravel Configuration (.env file):
Session Configuration:

```
SESSION_DRIVER=database
SESSION_DOMAIN=.example.com
SESSION_SAME_SITE=none
```

Sanctum Configuration:

```
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=example.com,dashboard.example.com,marketplace.example.com
```

Nuxt Configuration (.env):
Axios Configuration:

```
API_ENDPOINT=https://api.example.com
```

Nuxt Auth Configuration:

```
APP_URL=https://example.com
APP_URL_DASHBOARD=https://dashboard.example.com
```

Nuxt Auth Strategy:
I'm using the Laravel Sanctum strategy in Nuxt:

```
auth: {
  strategies: {
    'laravelSanctum': {
      provider: 'laravel/sanctum',
      url: process.env.API_ENDPOINT,
      endpoints: {
        login: { url: '/api/auth/login', method: 'post',  propertyName: 'token' },
        logout: { url: '/api/auth/logout', method: 'post' },
        user: { url:'/api/user', method: 'get', propertyName: false }
      }
    },
    // Other strategies...
  },
  redirect: {
    login: `${process.env.APP_URL}/auth/login`,
    logout: `${process.env.APP_URL}/auth/login`,
    callback: `${process.env.APP_URL}/auth/login`,
    home: process.env.APP_URL_DASHBOARD ?? '/'
  }
}
```

**Problem**:
When a user logs in from the root domain (example.com), I can retrieve the authenticated user using `this.$auth.user()`. However, when navigating to subdomains like dashboard.example.com, the authenticated user is not being recognized (`this.$auth.user()` returns `null`).

Expected Behavior:
I want the user session to be shared across all subdomains after logging in from the root domain.

Additional Information:

- Laravel version: 8
- Nuxt.js version: 2
- Laravel Sanctum middleware (`EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful`) is configured appropriately.

I appreciate any insights or guidance on resolving this session sharing issue. Thank you!